# MUI (Material UI) data grid in a grid parent: The MUI data grid does not resize as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a parent grid `<div>` container, which wraps two children. One is the MUI `<DataGrid />`, and the other is a `<div>` element:

JSX (React):

```
<div className="container">
  <DataGrid
    rows={someRows}
    columns={someColumns}
  />
  <div className="somethingElse">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}
```

What I expect:

1. `<DataGrid />` and `<div className="somethingElse">` stay side by side, where `<DataGrid />` takes 3/4 of the entire window width and `<div className="somethingElse">` takes 1/4.
2. When a user resizes the window, the 3/4 and 1/4 division persists, but the widths of both of them expands or shrinks based on the resizing.

However, in reality: When resizing the window, the size of `<DataGrid />` doesn't change.

Is there any styling rules I need to change in order to achieve the correct grid behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Applying min-width: 0 to the grid parent element gives the expected behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-noyce-w2dknc